# Git clone with ssh does nothing

Tags: git, github, ssh, connection, wifi

If I try to clone a repo with:

```
MacBook:Git User$ git clone git@github.com:User/Betriebssysteme.git
```

it will stuck at

```
Cloning into 'Betriebssysteme'...
```

and wont go any further.

I'm using the new MacBook Pro and added a ssh-key.
If I'm working with the http download from git it works fine.
The repository is private.

**EDIT:** I found out, that my WLAN isn't good enough to handle it. If I'm going to connect my PC with LAN it works.

Can I make my WLAn better? It's already in a good position.

Comment: Try the clone in verbose mode, maybe we'll get some more clues: `git clone -v git@github.com:User/Betriebssysteme.git`

Comment: @nnyby nothing changed. But thank you

Comment: Can you successfully `ssh git@github.com`?  You should see a message along the lines of `Hi peeety! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: Did you add the ssh key that you are using to GitHub?

Comment: @larsks nothing is happening. No error, nothing. Just an empty line and it's loading.

Comment: @InnovativeInventor yes

Comment: @larsks I found out, that the problem is my WLAN, it's not good enough to handle that.

Comment: @Peeety What do you mean? Are you not connected to reasonably fast internet?

Comment: @InnovativeInventor sorry for the late response. My EasyBox couldn't handle the ssh-protocol. Had to buy a FRITZ!Box 7490 and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My EasyBox couldn't handle the ssh-protocol. Had to buy a FRITZ!Box 7490 and now it works.The easybox 804 can't work with ssh.